# AngularJS ui-router reverting to otherwise when ng-click is used

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

I'm playing around with AngularJS as a learning exercise.  I'm trying to get to grips with AngularJS ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and I've hit a bit of a brick-wall with an issue I'm having.

I've put a plunk together to illustrate and reproduce.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OvmOKPMfeFqNWc7ToCff?p=preview

The above is a simple wizard type component with tabs across the top to move to a particular step, and some **next/back** buttons at the bottom to move to the next relevant page.

The tab navigation at the top works fine, and clicking along moves changes the view and URL accordingly.

However the behaviour of the next/back buttons are quite strange insofar they work the first time you click next, but not afterwards.  You should be able to see what I'm talking about in the plunk.

It's looks like it *tries* to navigate to the correct view, but then immediately reverts to the **otherwise** rule.

I've added hooks into the code to trace through in the console.  In essence all the **next/back** buttons do is called the relevant state so **$state.go("step1"), $state.go("step3")**, etc.

Hope I've provided enough info and would appreciate any insight anyone can bring.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the problem occur outside of the plunker in the same way?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned; this is a representation of the problem I'm having locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to remove the '#' from the href attr on the anchors.

Comment: +1 Freakin love you. I didn't catch that in the docs at all :(

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to figure out the exact cause, but it looks like the primary difference is with the provided `relative` stateObject that is passed to `$state.go()`.

If you debug the source for `ui-sref`, you will notice their use of the go function:

`$state.go(ref.state, params, { relative: base });`

If you compare the `base` object used by your links, and the default (`$state.$current`) used by your internal controller calls to `$state.go(nextStep)` you will notice obvious differences.

While I don't see exactly why these are causing your issue, you can likely rectify it by updating your ui architecture. Create a parent state to which all the steps are children, nesting ui-views. Then use the parent state controller to keep track of steps, and manage forward and backward movements.

Comment: I didn't go 100% for your suggestion, but it did point me into the codebase to see this little ditty:

  // HACK: This is to allow ng-clicks to be processed before the transition is initiated:
  $timeout(function() {
    $state.go(ref.state, params, { relative: base });
});

Adding the $timeout block seems to resolve the issue (partially at least).

Updated plunk at
http://plnkr.co/edit/yTp6FW4YCfAiPiOJIsrl?p=preview

Comment: Alternative solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/MGAEUqRwokcrgJDHp71E?p=preview (Note: Not using ui-router)